# Rails: How to insert a text_field without a form just to test the layout?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms, input

I am just doing the layout for my app at the moment and I want to insert a text.field that does nothing just to see how it looks. How can I do this?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

There are a few ways that could do what you want.

1) just write the static HTML

```
<input type="text" name="dummy" />
```

2) Using `text_field_tag`

```
<%= text_field_tag "dummy", nil %>
```

3) Building a dummy form using a form_for for a dummy object

```
<%= form_for SomeModel.new do |f| %>
  <%= f.text_field :column_name %>
<% end %>
```